# use dynamic data in dreamweaver CS6 to populate a hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, sql, variables, hyperlink, dreamweaver

Basically I have a news page which stores headlines, stories, and a unique story identifier in a SQL database.  I want to be able to create a hyperlink on a webpage to the pictures.

so when someone selects a news story from a drop down menu (which uses the headline) and presses submit I want to pass the storyID, which is a unique identifier, to a spot in a hyperlink. so if it was story 134 then then link would look like:

I know the SQL statement would look like:

SELECT StoryID from db.News
Where Headline = {The headline selected in the dropdown menu}

the dropdown menu is called NewsDrop

this would be an ASPX page written with a VB code base

SO I guess I need help passing the variables along to the search string and the hyperlink.

Not even sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options available to achieve this, the most common would be to using a [**query string**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in the hyperlinks in your drop down menu to send a parameter to a SQL stored procedure which would use it in a variable in your select statement.  So basically the hyperlinks you have in the drop down menu would be appended with `?storyID=<uniquestoryid>` and on the far end `SELECT StoryID from db.News Where StoryID = @StoryID` it would be less efficient to use the headline from the link as a query string and variable in the where clause as you have shown but if that is your only option it could be done.

However you should proceed carefully when using query strings here is a **[link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)** to a good basic article about query strings and another **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867954/best-practices-in-using-querystring-in-asp-net)** about best practices.

Comment: I guess i forgot a part in there, and i thought I wrote it.  I wanted the Hyperlinks on the bottom of the page to be something like <a href="\images\{storyid}\pic1.jpg>  where the {storyid} would be pulled from whichever headline was picked in the dropdown menu.  that way I could have one basic web page that can be used and populated by 100's of stories.  plus it will save me a lot of time uploading pages each night. I was hoping to eventually get rid of the query strings on the web page HTML and put them in a VB script that can be called from the page.

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't know a VB script solution for that type of requirement.